# Is there such a thing as "emotional impedance"?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, emotion, psychology, emotional-expression

More specifically, what I would call *emotional reactance*. What this is would be the emotional equivalent of electrical reactance(which is the opposition to changes in voltage and current flow). So a person who experiences something that upsets them will be able to modulate those unpleasant emotions such that they decay rapidly with time(getting over it). As if there is some type of negative feedback at work in their brain circuitry.

Comment: Is your question based on just a hunch, or do you have sources you can refer to? What have you found out so far?

Comment: To some extent it is. And is there any evidence that supports this hunch or is there not? That is the gist of my question.

Comment: Often it is helpful for others if the asker provides some previous research they have done. For instance, your hunch tells you that emotions are negated over time, yet PTSD sufferers will tell you otherwise. Refining your question by specifying exactly what you are referring to helps to make the question more answerable